# New to Ajax, trying to load another page in a div but having issues with Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, safari

To continue off the title I'm trying to load another page that will be on the same domain onto my index page using the following markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#div1").load("test.html");
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now that works completely fine on both chrome and safari.  The trouble is when I try incorporating that into this layout here:

[CSS-Only Responsive Layout](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/06/12/css-only-responsive-layout-with-smooth-transitions/)

The links and buttons on the page "test.html" are no longer interactive in safari even though they still work in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be correct and should work.

but, in a local environment, javascript doesn't have the permissions to load files, did you try if this works on a server? or just locally?

Comment: yeah the code does work like i said it actually only works on a server like you said but when I insert it into that layout it is still not interactive in safari, as in the links and buttons are not working.

Comment: ah, yeah that's because it only loads the html, not the javascript. Maybe you can solve this by using a little bit of PHP? `<?php include("test.html"); ?>`
you can put this inside the div. Oh, and you'll have to rename your file to .php in stead of .html

Comment: Yeah so unfortunately that didnt work I saved it as a php and then loaded that instead and still no response on clicks.

Comment: ok, may I ask how the clicks work? are they just `<a href="">`'s? or with javascript

Comment: they actually are just <a href =" "> but they're in a table  I even went so far as to just try manually placing the entire page in a div and placing that in the original page but to no avail.  to give you a better idea heres a link to the actual page: [link](http://whymzicalwijabz.com/) <<this still uses the iframe which contains the following page:[link](http://whymzicalwijabz.com/HappyHeart.html)